# how to render template use liquid gem with html, css file and asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, liquid

I have a folder with html files, css and assets.
The folder tree is shown below:

[image]

Folder `ifreezeapp` is in folder `public`

When i try to parse and render file `index.html` in view

```
Liquid::Template.parse( File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/ifreezeapp/index.html") ).render().html_safe
```

It loads incorrect assets,css,js....

How to render template that can load the correct assets,css,js,...

Comment: What does it load? We need more information.

Comment: You mean, the files dont load ? Like the links to js, css are failing ?

Comment: You're probably referencing those assets with the wrong path. Can you show how you're including your css on index.html as an example?

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim : include like this
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-lightbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo_themes/default/default.css">`

Comment: @PamioSolanky: it load with wrong links

Comment: @báchtrầnnguyên Try including like this: `/ifreezeapp/css/owl.theme.css`